# Identical question for multiple programming languages

Tags: support

I have a question that concerns itself with a programming language's standard library, and I would like an answer for multiple languages.
I already have an answer [for one language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20668996/1707076), but when I tried to compose a new question with similar content for the next language, the site let me know that I could not post, because the question was too similar to my first question.

Since I already have answers for that question, I think I should not modify the question. Also, since I can only accept one answer, I can't accept all correct answers for each language.

What is the norm in a situation like this, and how do I get my answer for the other languages?

Comment: Is this for a real situation or do you want a handy to reference list of related questions?

Comment: Is it really a list of specific languages you're looking for? Or is your question simply language agnostic?

Comment: @Bart: I don't think it is language agnostic, since it concerns itself with the standard library of each of these languages.

Comment: Is it that regex question? Because most language I'm familiar with have the verbose modifier available - which was the answer to that question. And certainly now that you know of the verbose flag, you'd be able to search for "regex verbose in language X"

Comment: @OGHaza: ah, I guess I might have my answer to that specific question... I'll give that a try. Thanks mate! I am still curious though what the norm is for other situations.

Comment: I would imagine it would be difficult to have a question that was cut and paste between languages without failing "minimum understanding"

Comment: @DudeOnRock yes but I mean if you show your attempt to solve the problem in each case (presumably different in each case) then the question will be different enough

Comment: A question for multiple languages would probably be "too broad"; good questions have a single correct answer, not 3 or 4 of them.  If you want to know the algorithmic approach language-agnostic to something, that's fine, but if you want to know the C++, Java, Haskell solution to how to do something specific, that's not, and should be multiple questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally a question looking for code should demonstrate a "minimum understanding of the problem being solved". This is usually achieved by providing your own attempts at a solution. Your attempt will presumably be different for each language and so your questions will be sufficiently different

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist